# Optional arguments on both ends

Tags: c#, overloading

```
static void F(string ham, object jam = null) { }  
static void F(string spam, string ham, object jam = null) { }  
...  
F("meat product", null);
```

The developer of this odd code is apparently attempting to make optional parameters on both ends; the intention is that both spam and jam are optional, but ham is always required.

Which overload does the compiler pick, and why?

(*I got the question from  [blog of Eric Lippert](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/10/optional-arguments-on-both-ends.aspx)*)

Comment: What's an "object", and what's "null"? They're not part of Standard C++. Without knowing what constructors object has, it's impossible to fully answer this problem. You sure this isn't C# code or something?  Anyway, if `null` isn't something that's valid for a single argument to the string constructor, then it can only match the first overload.

Comment: It is C# and this is the blog entry http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/10/optional-arguments-on-both-ends.aspx

Comment: @Christian: oh dear... I'll change the tags. (As per the blog, in C# the second overload is chosen, with reasons very clearly given - so, what the question on here for - what's not understood?)

Comment: Think of it in this way. `jam` is an optional parameter. If no parameter is passed, it will default to `null`. Since you are explicitly passing `null`, `null` has to be converted into an object/string. Thus the call to the second overload.

Answer (score 0):

> The second overload is chosen. (Were you surprised?)
>
> The reason why is straightforward. The
>   overload resolution algorithm has two
>   candidates and must pick which is the
>   best one on the basis of the
>   conversions from the arguments to the
>   formal parameter types. Look at the
>   first argument. Either it is converted
>   to string, or to... string. Hmph. We
>   can conclude nothing from this
>   argument, so we ignore it.
>
> Now consider the second argument. We
>   either convert null to object, if we
>   pick the first overload, or to string,
>   if we pick the second overload. String
>   is obviously more specific than
>   object; every string is an object, but
>   not every object is a string. We
>   strive to pick the overload that is
>   more specific, so we choose the second
>   overload, and call

```
F("meat product", null, null);
```

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/10/optional-arguments-on-both-ends.aspx

Comment: Yeah, now that the quote from Eric Lippert's blog has been re-posted here, it's much clearer... lol :D